# Is browsing the internet during windows update or an antimalware scan safe?

Tags: internet, windows-update, anti-virus

Over 15 years ago (around 2000), my father never allowed me to use the computer while he was running a virus scan or Windows Update. Can I safely use Google Chrome for normal internet use (Youtube, Netflix, forums, social media) while I'm updating Windows through Windows Update or running a scan using Norton 360 or other antivirus software?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, for the most part.

with AV scans, assuming that your PC is not overtaxed, there is no reason to avoid simple activities. you might want to avoid playing games or other very intense usecases while a virus scan is occuring, but other than the potential to overheat, there is no danger.

Windows update is mostly safe to do while performing other tasks, with the caveat that if a file needs to be replaced, it must not be open for read/write at that time. Nowadays, Windows is good about replacing files during shutdown and restart, making file replacements safer. At worst, you might receive an error during installation, and have to try again later.

Comment: i would add norton 360 uses a lot of resourses doing background scan, anyway avoide to use the computer is not neccesary but you should assume the performance inpact(avoid games 100%)